# How to check if a script is already running

Tags: python-3.x, process, windows-10, reload

How do you check if your script is already running to prevent it from running/opening multiple times.
I am aiming for it to either quit and allow the script to open again or stop the new one from running.

Using:
Python 3.8
Windows 10
File type .pyw
Ide: Thonny

I have looked and haven't been able to find a answer.

Comment: how many python programs can you run at once?

Comment: Just trying to run one program but i don't want it to being run multiple times at the same time. Basically i  don't want it to run a bunch of times like when you click the browser and it opens tons of windows